# instantiated class is nil when called inside viewdidload()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null, viper-architecture

I am trying to learn the VIPER architecture model and one thing I can't figure out is when I do the following:

1. Instantiate promotionPresenter class
2. Instantiate promotionsViewController
3. assign promotionsViewController.presenter = (instantiated promotionPresenter class from step 1)
4. try to access the instantiated presenter class from inside viewdidload() function within promotionviewController class.
5. presenter is nil.
   Why is presenter nil? I already instantiated it.

```
import UIKit

/*
 * The Router responsible for navigation between modules.
 */

class PromotionsWireframe : PromotionsWireframeInput {

    // Reference to the ViewController (weak to avoid retain cycle).
    var promotionsViewController: PromotionsViewController!
    var promotionsPresenter: PromotionsPresenter!
    var rootWireframe: RootWireframe!

    init() {
        let promotionsInteractor = PromotionsInteractor()
        // Presenter is instantiated
        promotionsPresenter = PromotionsPresenter()
        promotionsPresenter.interactor = promotionsInteractor
        promotionsPresenter.wireframe = self
        promotionsInteractor.output = promotionsPresenter
    }

    func presentPromotionsIntefaceFromWindow(_ window: UIWindow) {
        //view controller is instantiated
        promotionsViewController = promotionsViewControllerFromStoryboard()
        //presenter of view controller is assigned to instantiaed class
        promotionsViewController.presenter = promotionsPresenter
        promotionsPresenter.view = promotionsViewController
    }

    private func promotionsViewControllerFromStoryboard() -> PromotionsViewController {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "PromotionsStoryboard", bundle: nil )
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "promotionsViewController") as! PromotionsViewController
        return viewController
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class PromotionsViewController : UIViewController,    PromotionsViewInterface {

    // Reference to the Presenter's interface.
    var presenter: PromotionsModuleInterface!
    var promotions: [Promotion]!

    /*
     * Once the view is loaded, it sends a command
     * to the presenter asking it to update the UI.
     */

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // getting error because presenter is unwrapped as nil
        self.presenter.updateView()
    }

    func showPromotionsData(_ promotions: [Promotion]) {

        // need to implement
    }
}
```

---

```
import Foundation

class PromotionsPresenter : PromotionsModuleInterface, PromotionsInteractorOutput {

    // Reference to the View (weak to avoid retain cycle).
    var view: PromotionsViewInterface!

    // Reference to the Interactor's interface.
    var interactor: PromotionsInteractorInput!

    var wireframe: PromotionsWireframe!

    func updateView() {
        self.interactor.fetchLocalPromotions()
    }

    func PromotionsFetched(_promotions: [Promotion]) {
        // need to implement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take this boilerplate (https://github.com/CheesecakeLabs/Boilerplate_iOS_VIPER) and read this post (https://www.ckl.io/blog/best-practices-viper-architecture/) in order to learn not only how to correctly initialize your VIPER modules, but also how to **automate VIPER files creation and initiazlization**

Comment: This answer does in fact set OP's question on firmer separation-of-concerns ground.  Conversely, this answer could be improved by answer's author meticulously revealing Boilerplate_iOS_VIPER's improved separation of concerns among the view, interactor, presenter, entities, routing zones.  This answer is unfortunately tarnished by being effectively a link-only answer (which it doesn't need to be).  This is unfortunate, because by viewing the linked webpages, Marcelo Gracietti's larger message (but unfortunately omitted here on StackOverflow's answer) is much of the true answer that OP needs.